# razor assignment error

Tags: asp.net, razor

```
if(Request.QueryString["UserId"] !== WebSecurity.CurrentUserId){
    Response.Redirect("~/AdminError");
}
```

what is wrong with the above expression ? Please help
it says

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '=='
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra `=` sign. `!==` is not legal in C#, `!=` is.

The compiler sees this as a sequence of the tokens `!` (logical negation) and `==` and complains that negating the operator `==` does not make sense.